# Top Banner border width sizing?

Tags: html, css

so I am a bit confused about some of my code and why it isn't working?   The top header border which has navigation buttons which direct the user to different places within the site.  I am trying to make the width fit screen and for some reason, there is a small gap where the black bar doesn't fill on the top left.

[image: Screenshot of banner]

Code is below:

```css
#top-menu-conainer2 {
  height: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  width: 4000px;
}

#top-menu-item2 {
  width: 4000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a.bolder_link {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.top-menu-item2 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.top-menu-item2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #F8F9FA;
}

#header-details {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 5000px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 600rem;
  border-right: 600rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
  .top-menu-container2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
  .top-menu2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:2000px) and (min-width:850px) {
  .mobile-menu2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Start Test Code For NEW banner-->
<div id="top-menu-container2">
  <div class="top-menu-item2">
    <div class="top-menu2" id="top-menu2">
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="index.asp" title="Home Page" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">Home</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="aboutus.asp" title="About Us" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">About Us</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="gallery.asp" title="Gallery" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">Gallery</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="brochures.asp" title="Brochures" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">Brochures</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="testimonial.asp" title="Testimonial" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">Testimonial</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="top-menu-item2">
        <li><a href="checkout.asp?action=login.asp" title="Log-In/Sign-Up" class="bolder_link" style="color:#FFFFFF">Login/Sign-Up</a></li>
      </div>

      <div style="background-color: #000000">
        <div id="header-details">


          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Test Code for NEW banner-->
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing any of your code (css/html)?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML/CSS so one can see what you might have messed up?

Comment: Apologies, I will now.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I was having troubles with the CSS code formatting properly but it's all good now, thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Dude please check your code first ... plenty div-tags aren't closed and you are missing '=' after classes ...

Comment: Sorry, I am new to some code. I am learning as I go sort of situation. Sorry if I have been stupid.

Comment: @RNH
Right, I see what you mean now, I was being stupid haha.   I have got the closing tags now for the div's and added the = to my classes.   But I am still having the same issue with the border now filling the top completely and leaving a gap on the left.   I will update my code.

Comment: You still got plenty of errors in there. `li` must be a child of a list element (ul/ol), it can not be a direct descendant of `div`. And you have a stray `</ul>` in there that has no opening counterpart. You should validate your code to find such errors - https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: `.top-menu-item2` has `padding-left: 30px;`, so all of its content is offset 30px from the left, and that includes the div you are using to apply the black background here. There are quite a few things that are not done “properly” here, but have been hacked into place using rather crude workarounds, that background div being one of them.

Comment: Okay thank you all for all the help I will give it all ago and sorry again for making simple mistakes in my code, I guess it's just obvious for people that have been learning code for some time.  I am fairly new and not 100% on everything just yet but once again thank you for all the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}


#top-menu-conainer2{
  background: #000000;
}

.top-menu-item2{
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a{
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#top-menu-item2 li a.bolder_link{
  font-weight: 700;
}

.top-menu-item2 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.top-menu-item2 li a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #F8F9FA;
}

#header-details{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 5000px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 600rem;
  border-right: 600rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width:850px){
  .top-menu-container2{
     display:none !important;} 
   }
@media screen and (max-width:850px){
  .top-menu2{
    display:none !important;
  } 
}

@media screen and (max-width:2000px) and (min-width:850px){
  .mobile-menu2 {
     display: none !important;
   }
}
```

Improvements on naming and using classes instead of id's